# How to compile tcl/shell code (Hide original source code)

Tags: shell, compilation, hide, tcl, source-code-protection

Please  help with the step by step instructions on "**How to compile tcl/ shell code**"
 (Need to hide original source code)

Please come out with answers considering the following queries

1. Tools need to accomplish that (Please suggest the best/simple one)
2. How to compile
3. How to run the compiled output file

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activestate offers a product, the ["Tcl Dev Kit" (TDK)](http://www.activestate.com/tcl-dev-kit), which can be used to produce byte-compiled blobs and to otherwise prepare "compiled" applications written in Tcl (also known as "starpacks").

Comment: A lesser version of this is to just put everything in a starpack yourself (with [`sdx`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3411)). Not as safe, but still enough to defeat random finger-pokers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Linux you can use Freewrap to compile tcl. If your distribution doesn't have it in it's repository download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/freewrap/ and just pass the name of your tcl script as the argument like this:

```
freewrap <name>.tcl
```

This should generate the file `<name>`, which you can run as any executable. See http://wiki.tcl.tk/855 for other options.

To compile shell scripts use `shc`. The tool can be downloaded from http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Shells/shc-18503.shtml and you compile your shell script with the command

```
shc -f <name>
```

This should output two files `<name>.x` and `<name>.x.c`. The former is the executable you want and the other is a C code file compiled from your original script that is used to generate the executable.

Answer (score 0):

After almost a decade.

To compile `.tcl` script, you need `TclKit` and `sdx`. You can download them from [TclKits: Downloads](https://tclkits.rkeene.org/fossil/wiki/Downloads) and [Google Code Archive | Downloads](https://code.google.com/archive/p/tclkit/). (I used one for RHEL5 x86_64 on Ubuntu.)

After making `TclKit` executable by

```
$ chmod +x tclkit-8.*.*-*-*
```

, the command

```
$ tclkit-8.*.*-*-* sdx-*.kit qwrap *.tcl
```

will compile a script file and generate `*.kit` file. To run it:

```
$ tclkit-8.*.*-*-* *.kit
```